# barryvdh/laravel-dompdf page break after table head

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am using dompdf in laravel and I am trying to generate invoices to a pdf. Now I have the problem, that the first row is too long for the first page. It is moving to the second page, what is exactly right. Unfortunately I now have the table header on the first page without any table row. Just tried to move it with "page-break-after: avoid" and "page-break-before: always" but it does not work.

Comment: if you found a good solution please add here. thanks im also facing that kind issue